# JMeter Non-GUI mode (Command line) execution - Tidying up

Tags: jmeter

I'm executing Jmeter from command line using following command

!JMeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -Jsummariser.out=false -n -t .jmx -l JmeterReports\TestReport.xml -j JmeterReports\jmeter.log

At the end of the run, **I get a tidying up message and it takes 50 mins.** Any hint on how to avoid this. it impacts my testing time.

00:08:42.083  login ticket value is :: LT-1418054-HsUfB5qYlXKKhrnJGGcoGeCeQtTf5

00:59:51.971  Tidying up ...    @ Tue Mar 22 12:30:26 CET 2022 (1647948626380)
00:59:51.971  ... end of run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all consider disabling all these [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) overrides as storing all requests and responses data into the .jtl file for one hour test causes massive disk IO, moreover writing XML is more resource intensive process than default CSV output
2. If the problem is still there take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and inspect what the threads are doing and which are stuck or waiting
3. Monitor the JVM metrics using [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) or equivalent, it might be the case JVM does excessive [garbage collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) due to low heap space or something like this

More information:

- [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I will try above all